# Is there a version control software or something for little code snippets in Kusto

Tags: git, version-control, kql

I'm trying to find a version control software for queries in Kusto (something similar to SQL).
I have a lot of small queries that do different things, and people make changes to them to get them to do their respective stuff. So far my teammates are using OneNote to keep these queries, but I find that it's just too unresourceful.
I've used GitHub before. However, I've used it only for big programs that required contributions from different people but in all it was just one big program.
So, is there anything that I could use to keep track of different little code snippets I'm writing in Kusto?

Thank you.

Comment: What issue do you see with using GitHub for small code snippets? There is no restrictions on how small a project can be and you can have many small snippets in a single repo. You can also check out https://gist.github.com/ which is a tool made for sharing version controlled code snippets and notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want version control for DevOps purposes, then you'll find this doc useful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops